# Mnesia: Will post-netsplit restores copy entire table?

Tags: erlang, mnesia

Under mnesia with majority tables, when a netsplit occurs, a fully consistent, connected system can be restored by setting the mnesia master nodes to the majority island, and restoring the minority tables from there. As Ulf Wiger puts it:

> If mnesia discovers a split-brain situation, it will issue an event,
>   "running partitioned network". One way to respond to this would be to
>   set master nodes to the "island" that you want to keep, and then
>   restart the other nodes. When they come back up, they will
>   unconditionally load tables from the master nodes.

My question is whether the minority will copy the entire table from the majority or whether it will only copy those transactions that have occurred since the netsplit.

Note that I am not asking about Wiger's netsplit, but the default mnesia behavior of setting some master nodes and then restarting the other ones.

Comment: Is this question about Ulf Wiger's unsplit https://github.com/uwiger/unsplit or about mnesia in general? My understanding is that mnesia doesn't keep records of transactions - there is only the current transaction, so it wouldn't know which transaction are different and therefore would be synchronizing full tables.

Comment: @Amiramax I edited the question (it's not about unsplit).

Comment: Probably this answer will give you a more detailed information about mnesia's behaviour: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624570/online-mnesia-recovery-from-network-partition